# Microsoft Face API stopped working when sending binary data

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, face-api

Last time we tested our application was on Tuesday, it was working well.
Today morning a long wait and timeout received from Microsoft when sending DETECT request with binary data in body. Nothing has changed between in our application.

I tested and my keys are okay (when they are not, we receive an answer but not 200, not a timeout).
When I try to DETECT using an URL, it is working (proper content-type and body of course)
Did anyone noticed the same, or using the API differently?

```
HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
HttpPost request = new HttpPost("https://westeurope.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/face/v1.0/detect?returnFaceLandmarks=false&returnFaceId=true");

request.addHeader("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", MY_KEY);
request.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");

HttpEntity entity = new ByteArrayEntity(Base64.getDecoder().decode(base64));

request.setEntity(entity);

response = client.execute(request);
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems it was not a problem at out side. Suddenly it started to work...Hopefully will stay this way.